# Mapping a object but it gives Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, next.js

I tried fetching bloomberg api but when I map over the response object to get title it gives me the following error
`Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.` 
here's code

````
         <div>
            {loading? <h1>Loading...</h1> :null}
            {data.map((item) => ( 
              <div className="mt-10 text-center">
                <h1 className="text-2xl">{item.title  }</h1>
                <a href={item.longURL}>Visit</a>
                </div>))
                }
          </div>```


full code - https://github.com/Anurag30112003/FinApp/blob/main/pages/index.tsx
````

Comment: When you console api response `result.news`,  it shows all data correctly?

Comment: yes ! , It shows the api response correctly

Comment: Links might become absolute over time, you need to add necessary code in question. Also @Anurag you have not defined type of that object which is why you are getting error at `title`. @ClusterH's answer sums it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping render even when you did not fetch api yet, so data is empty array, there are no any elements yet. you need to add conditions only render if data is not empty. And also you need to add [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for mapping.

```
<div>
  {loading? <h1>Loading...</h1> :null}
  {data && data.length > 0 && data.map((item) => ( 
     <div className="mt-10 text-center" key={'your unique key in here'}>
        <h1 className="text-2xl">{item.title  }</h1>
        <a href={item.longURL}>Visit</a>
     </div>
    ))
   }
</div>
```

**Edit:** You need to correct type in `useState` instead of `const [data, setData] = useState([])`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState<IData[]>([]);
```

Here, you need to define your api response type properly. For example as below:

```
interface IData {
  id: number
  title: string
  longURL: string
}
```

Comment: Not working still giving same error

Comment: @Anurag, you need to define your data type correctly in `useState`, Check what type should be for your api response and use it as I updated answer.